# How to get regular interval count

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

So I have the data in below format

```
const data = [
  { date: '01-07-2019' },
  { date: '02-07-2019' },
  { date: '03-07-2019' },
  { date: '04-07-2019' },
  { date: '05-07-2019' },
  { date: '06-07-2019' },
  { date: '07-07-2019' },
  { date: '08-07-2019' },
  { date: '09-07-2019' },
  { date: '10-07-2019' },
  { date: '15-07-2019' },
  { date: '16-07-2019' },
  { date: '20-07-2019' },
  { date: '21-07-2019' },
  { date: '22-07-2019' },
  { date: '23-07-2019' }
]
```

So I have to count the regular interval dates. For example on date `{   date: '10-07-2019' }`, `{ date: '20-07-2019' }` and on `{ date: '23-07-2019' }` it breaks so count should be again started with 1.

```
const ouput = [{
    startDate: '01-07-2019',
    endDate: '10-07-2019',
    count: 10
}, {
    startDate: '15-07-2019',
    endDate: '16-07-2019',
    count: 2
}, {
    startDate: '20-07-2019',
    endDate: '23-07-2019',
    count: 4
}]
```

I did that

```
const output = Object.values(data.reduce((a, { startDate, endDate }, i) => {
  const startTime = moment(data[i].date)
    const endTime = moment(data[i + 1] && data[i + 1].date)
    if (moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime)).asDays === 1) {
    a.startDate = startDate
    a.startDate = endDate
  }
  a.count++;
  return a;
}, {}));
```

But it is not giving what I expect. Please help.

Comment: regardless what you're doing on reduce, you're never returning `a` (the accumulator), so on the second iteration it will be either null or undefined, which is not meant to work in any case. In any case, it's not clear what is the "regular interval date".

Comment: @briosheje Pls wait let me update the question

Comment: @briosheje Updated my question. Please have a look. And regular interval date means "Where the difference between two dates is greater than 1 day"

Comment: shouldn't that be 9 days, 1 day and 3 days? are you including the first date?

Comment: @briosheje Yes it will be included

Comment: @Profer Provided solution below. Check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with a function generator to handle the desired aggregation.

The below code will loop the dates, take a pair, check whether the start date exists, update the end date and automatically yield the value if necessary.

Comments are directly in the code below, the code assumes the initial array is already sorted as the example you mentioned.

As a side note, you're actually including the last date in the count, while, effectively, it should be one day less than your count. Further comments about that are available below in the function generator code.

```js
const data = [
  { date: '01-07-2019' },
  { date: '02-07-2019' },
  { date: '03-07-2019' },
  { date: '04-07-2019' },
  { date: '05-07-2019' },
  { date: '06-07-2019' },
  { date: '07-07-2019' },
  { date: '08-07-2019' },
  { date: '09-07-2019' },
  { date: '10-07-2019' },
  { date: '15-07-2019' },
  { date: '16-07-2019' },
  { date: '20-07-2019' },
  { date: '21-07-2019' },
  { date: '22-07-2019' },
  { date: '23-07-2019' }
];

// Counts intervals of consecutive dates.
function* countIntervals(dates) {
  // declare an initial accumulator.
  let acc = {
    count: 0
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    // get the currently looped value and the next one.
    const [curr, next] = [moment(dates[i].date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), dates[i+1] ? moment(dates[i+1].date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') : null];
    // if the current date and next days are valid and if the difference in days between them is 1..
    if (curr && next && (next.diff(curr, "days") === 1)) {
      // Then keep track of the start date if not set, update the end date and increase the count of days.
      acc.startDate = acc.startDate || dates[i].date, acc.endDate = dates[i+1].date, acc.count++;
    }
    else {
      // otherwise, if the accumulator has a start date, yield the value.
      if (acc && acc.startDate) {
        acc.count++; // <-- comment this if you don't want the last date to be included.
        yield Object.assign({}, acc);
        // and init again the accumulator.
        acc = {
          count: 0
        };
      }
    }
  }
  // if the loop is finished and the progression continued, yield the current accumulator.
  if (acc.startDate) yield acc;
}

// usage...
const intervals = [...countIntervals(data)];
console.log(intervals);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a simple question why did you put asterisk to function?

Comment: @Profer the asterisk means it's a **function generator**, which is a function returning something **iterable** or, really, a **Generator** object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function* . Function generators are useful in many circumstances; you could do the same with a reduce cycle, but it would be slightly more complex and harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go, Try this**

```
const data = [
          { date: "01-07-2019" },
          { date: "02-07-2019" },
          { date: "03-07-2019" },
          { date: "04-07-2019" },
          { date: "05-07-2019" },
          { date: "06-07-2019" },
          { date: "07-07-2019" },
          { date: "08-07-2019" },
          { date: "09-07-2019" },
          { date: "10-07-2019" },
          { date: "15-07-2019" },
          { date: "16-07-2019" },
          { date: "20-07-2019" },
          { date: "21-07-2019" },
          { date: "22-07-2019" },
          { date: "23-07-2019" }
        ];
```

*function to parse date*

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.split("-");
  // new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]); // Note: months are 0-based
}
```

*function to get date difference*

```
function dateDiff(date1, date2) {
  date1 = parseDate(date1);
  date2 = parseDate(date2);
  let diffTime = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
  let diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return diffDays;
}
```

*Required output*

```
const output =  data.reduce(function(resultSet, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) {

  if (resultSet.length == 0) {
    resultSet.push({
      startDate: currentValue.date,
      endDate: currentValue.date,
      count: 1
    });
  }
  else{

    let dateDiffrence = dateDiff(resultSet[resultSet.length-1].endDate, currentValue.date);
    console.log(dateDiffrence);
    if(dateDiffrence == 1){
        resultSet[resultSet.length-1].endDate = currentValue.date;
        resultSet[resultSet.length-1].count++;
    }else{
        resultSet.push({
            startDate: currentValue.date,
            endDate: currentValue.date,
            count: 1
          });
    }

  }
  return resultSet;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possible solution.

```js
const parseDate = (str) => {
  const [d, m, y] = str.split('-');
  return +new Date(y, m - 1, d)
}

const output = data.reduce((a, {
  date
}, i) => {
  const cur = parseDate(date);
  const lastDate = data[i - 1] && data[i - 1].date || date;
  const last = parseDate(lastDate || date);

  if (cur - last > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) a.push({count: 0});

  const {
    startDate = date,
    count
  } = a.pop();

  a.push({
    startDate,
    endDate: date,
    count: count + 1
  })

  return a;
}, [{
  count: 0
}])

console.log (output)
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
  { date: '01-07-2019' },
  { date: '02-07-2019' },
  { date: '03-07-2019' },
  { date: '04-07-2019' },
  { date: '05-07-2019' },
  { date: '06-07-2019' },
  { date: '07-07-2019' },
  { date: '08-07-2019' },
  { date: '09-07-2019' },
  { date: '10-07-2019' },
  { date: '15-07-2019' },
  { date: '16-07-2019' },
  { date: '20-07-2019' },
  { date: '21-07-2019' },
  { date: '22-07-2019' },
  { date: '23-07-2019' }
]</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you construct UTC dates there will be no need to use moment.js. With UTC every day is 24 hours and DST does not apply. This solution features a boilerplate function to handle the creation of the UTC date from your date string format.

```js
const data = [
  { date: '01-07-2019' },
  { date: '02-07-2019' },
  { date: '03-07-2019' },
  { date: '04-07-2019' },
  { date: '05-07-2019' },
  { date: '06-07-2019' },
  { date: '07-07-2019' },
  { date: '08-07-2019' },
  { date: '09-07-2019' },
  { date: '10-07-2019' },
  { date: '15-07-2019' },
  { date: '16-07-2019' },
  { date: '20-07-2019' },
  { date: '21-07-2019' },
  { date: '22-07-2019' },
  { date: '23-07-2019' }
];

const ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

function dateStrToUTC(dateStr) {
  const dateParts = dateStr.split('-');
  const utcDate = new Date();
  utcDate.setUTCFullYear(dateParts[2]);
  utcDate.setUTCMonth(dateParts[1] - 1);
  utcDate.setUTCDate(dateParts[0]);
  utcDate.setUTCHours(0);
  utcDate.setUTCMinutes(0);
  utcDate.setUTCSeconds(0);
  utcDate.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
  return utcDate;
}

function getRegularIntervals(accumulator, currentValue) {
  const index = accumulator.length - 1;
  let daysPassed = 0;
  if (index > -1) {
    daysPassed = (dateStrToUTC(currentValue.date) - dateStrToUTC(accumulator[index].endDate)) / ONE_DAY;
  }
  if (index > -1 && 1 == daysPassed) {
    accumulator[index].endDate = currentValue.date;
    accumulator[index].count++;
  } else {
    accumulator.push({
      startDate: currentValue.date,
      endDate: currentValue.date,
      count: 1
    });
  }
  return accumulator; 
}

const output = data.reduce(getRegularIntervals, []);
  
console.log(output);
```

Output as expected:

```
[
  {
    "startDate": "01-07-2019",
    "endDate": "10-07-2019",
    "count": 10
  },
  {
    "startDate": "15-07-2019",
    "endDate": "16-07-2019",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "startDate": "20-07-2019",
    "endDate": "23-07-2019",
    "count": 4
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked your approach of using reduce function.

Going with the same, I just added some more logic in there and [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sohanchandak/xe9z3ob6/) is the final code.

```
// initially lets assume first date is the start as well as end date
var dateIntervalObject = {
  startDate: data[0].date,
  endDate: data[0].date,
  count: 1
};

var result = data.reduce((resultArray, obj, i) => {
  if(i > 0) {
    var startTime = moment(dateIntervalObject.endDate, "DD-MM-YYYY");
    var endTime = moment(obj.date, "DD-MM-YYYY");
    if (endTime.diff(startTime, 'days') === 1) {
      dateIntervalObject.endDate = obj.date;
      dateIntervalObject.count += 1;
      // remove the latest object in array, to replace with new
      resultArray.pop();
    } else {
        dateIntervalObject = {
        startDate: obj.date,
        endDate: obj.date,
        count: 1
      };
    }
    // push the date Interval object in the array
    resultArray.push(dateIntervalObject);
  }
  return resultArray;
}, [dateIntervalObject]);

console.log('result: ',result);
```

**Note:**

1. When initialState of the accumulator is passed to reduce function it starts iterating from 0th index, which in our case have already been initialized in the dateIntervalObject and therefore the first iteration with index value 0 is skipped.
2. Also, if the interval is not changing, we don't need to add another object to our result array but instead update the end date of the last element of our result array. Therefore, first pop and then push to just update the end date and count value.

Hope this helps!